# Symfony : Could not load type (overriding FOSUB)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am currently trying to override the FosUserBundle Registration Form. Indeed, after following Symfony's tutorial about it, I got this error message:

```
Could not load type "canapey_user_registration"
```

Here is my code :

```
namespace Canapey\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('latitude');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'canapey_user_registration';
    }
}
```

and config :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm                       
    firewall_name: main                     
    user_class:    Canapey\UserBundle\Entity\User 
    registration:
        form:
            type: canapey_user_registration
```

and services :

```
services:
    canapey_user.registration:
        class: Canapey\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        tags:
            - { name: canapey_user_registration, alias: canapey_user_registration}
```

After few checks, I've tried to use the service inside a controller, which worked. So it's likely that the services.yml isnt loaded while config.yml is running. And yet `services.yml` is imported.

So if you have any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `form.type` tag name to register the form type correctly.

Comment: I did it already, but it doesn't change anything unfortunately :'(

Answer (score 0):

Anyone has an idea ? Since know i have to directly write into fosuserbundle's type ....

Answer (score 0):

in services.yml, change

```
canapey_user.registration:
```

with

```
canapey_user_registration:
```